# Is the @NSManaged property thread safe?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobject

for example in the case:

```
@NSManaged public var myProperty: SomeType

func someFunc() {
    concurrentNSManagedObjectContext.perform {
        doSomething(with: self.myProperty)
    }
}
```

and what is the best practices, if yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@NSManaged` has no effect on thread safety. It helps Core Data manage the property but doesn't do anything about keeping the property safe for threads or anything else.

Using `perform` as you are is good if the `doSomething` function relates to Core Data, because `perform` and `performAndWait` are how Core Data manages thread safety. Accessing the property inside `perform` or `performAndWait` is safe; accessing it outside of those functions is usually not safe.

The only exception to the above is that if your managed object context uses main-queue concurrency (for example if you're using `NSPersistentContainer` and the context is the `viewContext` property) **and** you're sure that your code is running on the main queue, then you don't need to use `perform` or `performAndWait`. It's not bad to use them in that case but it's not necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

"Thread safety" at least in Apple Platforms thus far resolves to two things; reading, and writing. NSManaged object currently does not protect against a mix of the two. func doSomething(...) is going to throw an exception if some other thread is reading myProperty at time of mutation. Mutation can be done on a serial thread, however thread safety is more complicated than that. someFunc() is called by the first caller; if that caller is coming from a concurrent thread there is no guarantee of the order. If for example myProperty is of type Int and I call someFunc concurrent from 200 threads, the last thread may be 0 and someFunc may be += 1. Now if I make the func serial my end output is 1. So the short answer is it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. generally you are safe on a serial queue, but concurrent takes a lot of planning.